# How can i remove the last part in a string

Tags: c#, html, xml

I have a dynamic generated string as /directory/folder/filename.html

How can i remove the last part i.e /filename.html.

I want my output as /directory/folder/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) method in `System.IO`:

```
string path = "/directory/folder/filename.html";
path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

This *may* change the path seperator to the system default. If you want to preserve the slashes, use the following instead:

```
path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: It is a dynamic path and i want to remove the last split

Comment: @pavan that's what the above code does. If you need the ending slash, use `path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1` or append `/` (or `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`) to the result.

Comment: @pavan if you click the green tick mark next to an answer, you get some reputation and the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substring` *without using IO classes/method*.

```
string str = "/directory/folder/filename.html";
int endIndex = str.LastIndexOf("/");
endIndex = endIndex !=-1 ? endIndex : 0;
result = str.Substring(0,endIndex);
```

Comment: Note that this will break if there is no '/' in the string.

Comment: I think it is not required as per OP

Comment: Just because it works for a single example provided doesn't mean it will work for every single actual value he has.

Comment: Yes it could be possibility to have file name without folder but I assumed the other way, anyway updated my code as you pointed, I hope it will be okay.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only the path part use

```
string result = Path.GetDirectoryName(inputName);
```

If you want the filename and not the path

```
string result = Path.GetFileName(inputName);
```

Also I see that you use the forward slash. The methods above will give in output a folder separator correct for your operating system (forward or back slashes)